# String Index Out Of Range (Python) I have made bounds too

Tags: python

```
import time
password=input("What's your password?")
ans = ""
password=password.lower()
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
n = 0
a=0
starttime=time.time()
while ans !=password:
    print(a)
    for i in range(len(password)):
            letter=alpha[n]
            ans+=letter
            if ans[a] != password[a]:
                print(ans)
                ans = ans.replace(ans[a],"")
                n+=1
                break
            else:
                a+=1
                print(ans)
                n=0
                break
print("Password Found!")
endtime=time.time()
time=endtime-starttime
print("It took " + str(time) + " seconds!")
```

This is my code, sorry if i'm not posting it right (first time here). But let's digress, It seems i get an error of string index out of range

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Letter word cracker.py", line 15, in <module>
    if ans[a] != password[a]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I was wondering how to fix this, because its been eating at my brain for days. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through this?...

Comment: for my assessment, i was told to make a program to crack a password. I've created the number version however the letter one is harder. I've used random.randint which works but is too time consuming, so i was here asking you guys.

Comment: You have several variables and constructs that are either vaguely named or never used. I suggest stepping through your code by hand and sorting out what happens where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know why you are trying to do this, what you are trying to do, the error is here due to this line

```
ans = ans.replace(ans[a],"") ---> X
```

what replace will do, is replace all the occurrences of a particular character from the array, while you only need to remove the last.

For example :-

If ans = "naa", 
now replace will replace both 'a' while based on your logic you only want to remove the last element. because you have already matched till "na" and now in process of matching the third element.

You could probably do :-

```
ans = ans[:-1]
```

But again, this is a very very bad way to do this, because strings are immutable so you are basically creating and destroying strings every iteration.

One advice I would give is using list of characters instead of a string, it would not give a significant boost to the runtime for your program, for whatever reason you are using this.

EDIT:-
Also the for loop is unnecessary, as it is always breaking after first iteration. thanks @TigerHawk

---

```
import time
password=input("What's your password?")
ans = []
password=password.lower()
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
n = 0
a=0
starttime=time.time()
while "".join(ans) !=password:
    letter=alpha[n]
    ans.append(letter)
    if ans[a] != password[a]:
        ans.pop()
        n+=1
    else:
        a+=1
        n=0
print("Password Found!")
endtime=time.time()
time=endtime-starttime
```

Comment: The `for i in...` loop is unnecessary, as it always `break`s after the first iteration.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks for the tip, also is there a better way instead of using list here?

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been the best help! Although everyone elses has helped too. I guess i can still grow as a programmer

Answer (score 0):

This is a little better and more condensed version. From what I understand, you want to brute force a character string to compare it to a password.

```
import time
password=input("What's your password?")

password=password.lower()
alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

starttime=time.time()
for letter in range(len(password)):
    for index in range(len(alpha)):
        if alpha[index] == password[letter]:
            print "Letter",letter,"Found."
            next
print "Password Found!"
endtime=time.time()
time=endtime-starttime
print "It took",time,"seconds!"
```

Comment: Why do you have `next` in a statement by itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues per the previous post, but the IndexError is happening because you are comparing each element of each list, and when one list runs out, it raises the IndexError exception. Wrap that part of the code in an `if()` that checks to see whether there are any more elements left over.

This will *not* fix the entire program, and in fact, you'll likely need a better way to do this comparison... I'm just explaining why the IndexError is happening.

```
if (ans[a] and password[a]):
    if ans[a] != password[a]:
        print(ans)
        ans = ans.replace(ans[a],"")
        n+=1
        break
```

Comment: that is not where the problem is mate.... there is a logical issue here... of using replace...

Answer (score 0):

You should really go through your logic to understand why it isn't working, but there are many improvements you can make to your code. I have implemented a working version with a few improvements below.

```
from time import time
import string

#this will only work for a-z no whitespace, caps, numbers, etc.
pwd = raw_input("What is your password? ")
pwd = pwd.lower()
#create list of password for easier iterability
password = list(pwd)
#alphabet will have a-z lowercase
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
#empty list to start
guess = []
#start timer
start = time()

#outer loop through password
for char in password:
    #inner loop through alphabet
    for letter in alphabet:
        if letter == char:
            guess.append(letter)
            break

#print correct guess as string
end = time()
print "It took " + str(end - start) + " seconds to solve this password."

#verify correctness
print "".join(guess)
print pwd
```